# Sticking stream data to specific working

Tags: spark-streaming

We are trying to replace Apache Storm with Apache Spark streaming.
In storm; we partitioned stream based on "Customer ID" so that msgs with a range of "customer IDs" will be routed to same bolt (worker).
We do this because each worker will cache customer details (from DB).
So we split into 4 partitions and each bolt (worker) will have 1/4 of the entire range.

I did see comparison Spark and Storm; and this being limitation on Spark.
I am hoping we have a solution to this in Spark Streaming

Comment: what is the stream source?

Comment: Kafka, I am looking into SPARK directStream of Kafka but as experimental it is not working at all compared to regular Stream (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using Kafka, one way to address this problem is to partition your data at the producer side. As you probably have seen, Kafka messages have a key, and you may use that key to partition the data among partitions.

Using the Kafka receiver, you create one receiver per partition. Upon start of the Streaming  job, the receivers will be distributed over several executors.

This means that every executor (JVM) will be receiving data for only the partitions it's got assigned. This results on the same id going to the same executor for the lifetime of the receiver, and enables effective local caching as intended in the question.